# How does Laravel MessageBag work?

Tags: php, laravel

I encountered something magical about laravel (4.2), that i really want explaind how it could be possible.

When i up a MessageBag Class in **Class A**

And Pass that variable to **Class B**, somehow Class B overrides the Class A MessageBag without me declaring it.

```
class ClassA {

    public function test()
    {
        $msgBag = new \Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;

        new ClassB($msgBag);

        if($msgBag->any()) {
            #This will trigger and spit out "Message from Class B"
            dd($msgBag);
        }else{
            print('nope no messages');
        }
    }
}

class ClassB {

    protected $msgBag;

    function __construct(\Illuminate\Support\MessageBag $msgBag)
    {
        $this->msgBag = $msgBag;
        $this->setMessage();
    }

    public function setMessage()
    {
        $this->msgBag->add('message', 'Message from Class B');
    }
}
```

I tested the same thing with a normal object but that behaved like i expected it to.

```
class ClassA {

    public function test()
    {
        $object = (object) ['class'=>'A'];

        new ClassB($object);

        dd($object->class); # Will return A
    }
}

class ClassB {

    protected $object;

    function __construct($object)
    {
        $this->object = $object;
        $this->setMessage();
    }

    public function setMessage()
    {
        $this->object = (object) ['class'=>'B'];
    }
}
```

So obviously Laravel is doing something behind the seances to make this possible, but I haven't found it yet.

Does anyone know how to replicate this ?

Comment: Actually, this doesn't have anything to do with Laravel, it's just the (a little bit confusing) way how PHP 5 (and some other C-based languages like Java) handles objects (which is what a MessageBag is): http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php *"When an object is sent by argument, returned or assigned to another variable, the different variables are not aliases: they hold a copy of the identifier, which points to the same object."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Laravel magic here. In PHP, objects behave as though they are passed by reference (although they technically are not, but that's not relevant here).

This means that in your first example, the `MessageBag` object you created is the same object as the as the one assigned to `$this->msgBag` in `ClassB`. Therefore, any modifications made to the object inside `ClassB` are going to be seen when you inspect the `$msgBag` object in the `test()` method in `ClassA`.

This is not the case in your second example, because in your `setMessage()` method, you override the first object with an entirely new one.

Basically everything is behaving as you would expect with normal PHP.